# Python regex match number + unit

Tags: python, regex

I have a text from which I want to retrieve numbers+units of measurements, for instance: '3kg', '4mg', etc. Let's say x = '9mg'. The following regex does the job:

```
p = re.compile('[0-9][m|k]?g')
```

Then

```
p.findall(x)
```

returns '9mg'. Now I want to match more specific units like 'ml', 'ui', etc. The following regex

```
p = re.compile('[0-9](mg|kg|ml|ui)')
```

matches the parts of the string I'm interested in, however only returns the unit and not the number. For example,

```
p.findall(x)
```

returns 'mg' only, but the regex does not match for 'wmg', for instance, which is what I would expect. Can someone explain it why not the whole matched part is returned and how to get the proper regex?

Comment: Use `p = re.compile('[0-9](?:mg|kg|ml|ui)')`

Comment: *but the regex does not match for 'wmg'* - but `wmg` doesn't fit the rule *numbers+units*

Comment: If you use p = re.compile('[0-9](mg|kg|ml|ui)') it will show you only the strings that are containing exactly these letters, add ?: before each string to catch them all.

Comment: Thanks, adding ?: works!